# Cannot access a closed stream && HTMLWorker is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I'm trying to generate a PDF using iTextSharp and a StringBuilder (sb). I call it from within my controller as a function. I get the error "Cannot access a closed Stream.". Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitAsync(IFormCollection formCollection)
{
            /* Some Async logic for image verification */

            string sb = PdfTextBuilder(); // Generates a StringBuilder.ToString() to display in the PDF
            GeneratePdf(sb);

            /* Return & catch error statements
    }
```

GeneratePDF function:

```
private void GeneratePdf(string sb)
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb);

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();

    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();

    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    FileStream file = new FileStream("App_Data/imgs/test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    memoryStream.WriteTo(file);
    file.Close();


    memoryStream.Close();
}
```

For bonus points: I get the warning "HTMLWorker is obsolete". I know HTMLWorker is deprecated, yet it still seems to be working. How could I implement a new class to replace the obsolete HTMLWorker?

Comment: HTMLWorker has been replaced by XMLWorker, which has in turn been replaced by pdfHTML (iText 7). What version of iText are you using?

Comment: Instead of `memoryStream.WriteTo(file)` simply write `bytes` to the `file`.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Using iTextSharp version 5.5.13.1

Comment: 5.5.13.1 is the latest maintenance release of iText 5 .NET, and it has XMLWorker. (iTextSharp is the legacy name of iText 5 .NET)